# Cannot connect to flask running as a container from another container although I can ping

Tags: docker, flask, networking, containers

I have a docker-compose file as seen below.  The app and the flask are separate containers.  I cannot connect to "python" container although both are on the same network.  However, if I expose the port 5000 to the outside via port (e.g. - port: "9000:5000") then it is accessible.  However, I only want "app" to access the "python" internally and not from outside of host.

Isn't this possible?

```
version: '3' 
services:   
  python:
    build:
      context: ./docker/python

    image: python:3.6.12

    volumes:
      - IQData:/NMIQV2/Data
      - IQCode:/NMIQV2/Code
      - IQAnalysis:/NMIQV2/Analysis
    networks: 
      - base-network  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "5000:5000"
    networks: 
      - base-network
   
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
      - python
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo
      - python networks:    
          base-network:
            driver: bridge
```

python container Docker File:

```
FROM python:3.6.12 EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5000
# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /NMIQV2/Code
# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY src/ .

# copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask
server = Flask(__name__)

@server.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to?  From where?  What error do you get?  Can you fix the formatting in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: can you add docker-compose file for flask and app? the question is incomplete without those details.